# CWT matlab function

Tags: matlab, wavelet, transform

[image]

i'm trying to apply the cwt function from matlab in the first graph and from the different articles that i've read i should get something that shows different peaks to determine the location of damage, but all i'm getting is that spaghetti looking mess. is there a different approach to applying wavelet transform without using the built in function? thanks

Comment: Spaghetti happens because of the complex attitude of some CWT, that you already managed with Fourier.

Comment: does this mean that applying cwt to this signal is not possible?

Comment: That is possible, and possibly more informative than with Fourier, as the signal is not stationary.

Comment: your spaghetti is probably an artifact of your plot call, not the cwt

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem has to do with calling matlab’s plot function with complex values and not a problem with wavelets

Comment: Possibly, considering the wavelet transform can be real-valued

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to guess which signal you are analyzing, and the purpose, here is a demo, on a real signal, with half the Fourier spectrum, and the corresponding continuous wavelet transform scalogram.

Here, I suspect that the signal is too short (without further objectives) for FFT and CWT to yield interpretable results. The Matlab code is:

```
nsample = 64; % An odd number
timeSampling = 1/nsample;
time = (0:nsample-1)*timeSampling;
ratioSecondHalf = 20;
data = zeros(nsample,1);
data(1:nsample/2,1) = rand(nsample/2,1)-0.5;
data = medfilt1(data,5);
data(nsample/2+1:end,1) = rand(nsample/2,1)/ratioSecondHalf;

[fftR,fftAxe] = FFTR(data,timeSampling);

[cwtCoeff,cwfFreq] = cwt(data,1:64,'morl',timeSampling); 

figure(1);clf
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(time,data,'x-');;axis tight
xlabel('Time (a. u.)')
ylabel('Amplitude (a. u.)')
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(fftAxe,fftR,'x-');axis tight
xlabel('Frequency (a. u.)')
ylabel('Amplitude (a. u.)')
subplot(3,1,3)
h=imagesc('XData',time,'YData',2*cwfFreq/pi,'CData',abs(cwtCoeff));axis tight
xlabel('Time (a. u.)')
ylabel('Frequency (a. u.)')
```

FFTR.m is obtained from [here](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/Documents-Common/FFTR.m).

[image: Non-stationary signal, Fourier spectrum and continuous wavelet transform]

Comment: i've also tried this on a longer signal but it still gave me spaghetti i think it's because it's non-stationary like you said.

Comment: Abslute value is lacking somewhere

Comment: ANd the longer length is about interpretability, not spaghetti

Comment: i did it with absolute value and i got better results, no more spaghetti.

Comment: Good, spaghetti arise from plotting complex values as 2D points (real+imaginary)